# Digital output of the STM32L152RE: toggling between +/- V?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

Is it possible to get the digital data output from the STM32l152RE microcontroller to toggle between +/- volts? where the +V will represent the logic-1 and -V will represent the logic-0, instead of conventional 0 V as logic-0 and +V as logic-1.

Comment: You are asking two completely unrelated questions, this is not a good style to ask questions here. Please open a second question for your PWM question.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MCU can't output other digital voltages that is has, so it will only output 0V and 3.3V.

Comment: Then one should use the MCU output and build a circuit to attain the required digital voltage format? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the conversion must happen external to MCU.

Answer (score 3):

You could reference your output with a voltage divider like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL7GQq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could add a circuit to the output like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRnUe.png)</sup>